# Framework suitable for this Web service requirement

Tags: web-services, frameworks

I'm learning Software Engineering at University. My teacher give me this project : choose any ideas for website and MUST using any framework (and any languages) you want to develop this website.

I have ideas for my website is : sharing data (images, text ...) between users. For example, in system has userA, userB, and userC. UserA has resource B and B can access this. UserA still has resource C and userC can access this.

With this requirement. In short explanation:

1. can create new user.
2. can set permission for user
3. can building data base on permission

I don't know which framework exist to build most fastest for this project. I just care which framework can make me develop fast. (because I can learn a new language easily).

I has some knowledge in Ruby (suitable for Ruby on Rail), PHP  (suitable for framework base on this language) Python (suitable for Django) and Java. So, framework in those language maybe best.

Please help me. because this is a first time I work on framework (and components ...), so I really don't have any experience about any framework, strong/weak point of each ..

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm partial to Ruby on Rails so I'd use that.  Key gems would be:

1. devise - Authentication
2. cancan - Authorization
3. simple_forms - Tidy up data input
4. Twitter Bootstrap or Zurb Foundation - To make it look pretty

One of the easiest ways to get set up is to use the Rails Composer: http://railsapps.github.com/rails-composer/

It gives you a script that allows you to chose the exact configuration you want.